# Laravel storage, should I organize my files on database?

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-storage, laravel-storage

I have a web app where the user can upload files, create folders and stuff like that, I upload it on Google Cloud Storage, and organize it on a table `files` on my database, where I save the file name, path, size, extension, name, etc

But now I have a problem, if I rename a folder, I have to update multiples files on my database, update the folder and all the children, on storage I have to move each file to a new directory and delete all the content of the old directory

It seens to be too much just for a rename, I think the correct way to deal with the file manager should be just retriving the files directly from the storage and get over my database table

That is my question, **should I get over my files table?**

Comment: Google Cloud Storage does not have "folders', so you cannot rename one. If you are using the concept of folders with multiple objects, you must rename each object. The same for data stored in your table rows. If you are using a layer over Cloud Storage (gcsfuse or Laravel disk?) provide better details in your question.

Comment: @JohnHanley I just realized that, I can't rename a folder on GCS, so to "rename a folder" I have to create another one and move all the content, one by one to that new directory?

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm using laravel disk with a library `laravel-google-cloud-storage`

Comment: I am not sure what problem you are trying to solve. Indexing files is much faster in a local database than listing objects in Cloud Storage. However, I think your issue is a "design" challenge and not a technical problem. You must decide what feature you provide and balance the implementation tradeoffs. Once you have an on-topic programming question, update this question.

Comment: @JohnHanley It is a design challenge, on what community of stack should I ask it? I need to know if it is necessary to have the files in a database since when renaming it will have double of the work

Comment: Each Stack Exchange site has guides on how to use the site. Stack Overflow is for programming and software development so this is the right place EXCEPT you are asking for opinions. You need to do the work yourself by trying different methods, measuring results, and comparing to your goals. We cannot do that for you. Software development often involves 10x the work to do it correctly, securely, and performantly. You will seldom find shortcuts to delivering quality work. Either invest the time now or spend much more time later fixing your work. My comment is an opinion, there will be many ...